# Firebug keeps breaking on errors, and hangs pages

Tags: firefox, firebug

I have firebug installed, and it's indispensable as I'm a web developer, so I can't uninstall it.

But when I load Gmail or CNN or various other websites, it always pops up and breaks on javascript errors. I have tried disabling the Script tab, but it still happens.

I'm using Firefox 3.6 with Firebug 1.7.2 on Windows 7, but this also happens with Firefox 4 and the latest version of Firebug.

Has anyone seen or heard of this? Any ideas how to resolve?

Comment: Could you provide some more detail? E.g. which operating systems do you use?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 3.6 with Firebug 1.7.2 on Windows 7, but this also happens with Firefox 4 and the latest version of Firebug.

Comment: Same here with Firebug 1.9.1 on Firefox 10.0 after trying that weird pause icon. cjroebuck's answer helped me fix this annoying behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Check that the value `extensions.firebug.breakOnErrors` is set to false. To access and modify the value, type `about:config` in your firefox url bar. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that it shows errors from DIFFERENT tabs, happens to me too. Try to close all tabs (restart firefox) and keep only one you need